# ¿Cómo sabe el navegador que el Chapulín es Colorado?

Tags: html

Usando la propiedad `bgcolor` se puede especificar el color de fondo de la página. Los valores aceptados son cadenas de texto que deberían ser cualquier formato de color: hexadecimal, rgb, nombre...

Pero podríamos poner cualquier cadena de texto como valor; y así llegamos a un caso curioso, por ejemplo si ponemos como  color "Chapulín", que no es un valor válido:

```
<body bgcolor="Chapulin"></body>
```

Al hacer eso, el fondo de la página se vuelve de color rojo. ¿Cómo sabe el navegador que el Chapulín es Colorado? ¿Por qué ocurre así?

> Esto es una variante de una de mis preguntas favoritas de StackOverflow. Sé que está un poco anticuada (y que es mitad en broma, mitad en serio) pero siempre me ha parecido un caso interesante.

Comment: Ya se hizo esta pregunta @AlvaroMontoro.

Comment: @rnd Ah, estaba en móvil y no la encontré. Deja y cuando llegue a un ordenador la marcaré como duplicada para que se cierre.

Comment: Pero esta mola más por como está planteada y porque aparece Chapulín y no Chuck Norris

Comment: @blonfu ten cuidado, Chuck Norris es la única persona en el mundo capaz de propinar una paliza mortal vía correo electrónico (o comentario de SO). Cuando lea eso, se va a enfadar.

Comment: La idea es la misma, así que aunque esté planteada de manera diferente, es un duplicado. Aunque estoy en desacuerdo con el -1: que sea duplicado no significa que sea una mala pregunta. En mi opinión, la gente tiene un concepto equivocado de lo que es un duplicado.

Comment: Por supuesto, pero aún sabiendo que va a ser cerrada me ha sacado una sonrisa. Solo por eso merece la pena haberla hecho

Comment: Me parece una buena pregunta, aunque esté duplicada, pues es un dado interesante y curioso, la verdad nunca había puesto algo como "chucknorris" o "chapulin" en el _bgcolor_, me parece divertido e interesante, es una de las curiosidades del mundo de la informática.

Comment: Jajajajajja... que buena pregunta (+1)